# Radio button always take boolean 0 in laravel

Tags: php, database, html, laravel-5, radio-button

I have created radio button fields as follows

**EDIT: I have changed form as suggested in comments**

```
<div class="form-group">
    {!! Form::label('is_kids_friendly','Kids Friendly:') !!}
    {!! Form::radio('kidsfriendly', 'true', null),'&nbsp', 'Yes' !!}
    {!! Form::radio('kidsfriendly', 'false', null),'&nbsp','No' !!}
</div>

<div class="form-group">
    {!! Form::label('is_kids_only','Kids Only:') !!}
    {!! Form::radio('kidsonly', 'true', null),'&nbsp', 'Yes' !!}
    {!! Form::radio('kidsonly', 'false', null),'&nbsp','No' !!}
</div>

<div class="form-group">
    {!! Form::label('sineor_citizan_friendly','Sineor Citizan Friendly:') !!}
    {!! Form::radio('seniorcitizen', 'true', null),'&nbsp', 'Yes' !!}
    {!! Form::radio('seniorcitizen', 'false', null),'&nbsp','No' !!}
</div>
```

As this is radio button field, i have used `boolean` in database.
Each time, i fill in details, It takes `0`. Also, i can select multiple radio button, thats should not happen.
Am i doing something wrong?

Comment: How are you saving the values in database? Show your code.

Comment: `public function store(EventRequest $request)
    {
        Event::create($request->all());
        return redirect('event');
}`

Comment: Can you also share your Event Model code?

Comment: `class Event extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'event';
    protected $fillable = [
        'id',
        'title',
        'category',
        'subcategory',
        'description',
        'contact_person',
        'contact_number',
        'email',
        'country_id',
        'state_id',
        'city_id',
        'detailed_address',
        'fees',
        'is_kids_friendly',
        'is_kids_only',
        'senior_citizen_friendly',
    ];
}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should do following changes then your controller query will work as you want!

```
    <div class="form-group">
    {!! Form::label('is_kids_friendly','Kids Friendly:') !!}
    {!! Form::radio('is_kids_friendly', true, null),'&nbsp', 'Yes' !!}
    {!! Form::radio('is_kids_friendly', false, null),'&nbsp','No' !!}
</div>

<div class="form-group">
    {!! Form::label('is_kids_only','Kids Only:') !!}
    {!! Form::radio('is_kids_only', true, null),'&nbsp', 'Yes' !!}
    {!! Form::radio('is_kids_only', false, null),'&nbsp','No' !!}
</div>

<div class="form-group">
    {!! Form::label('sineor_citizan_friendly','Sineor Citizan Friendly:') !!}
    {!! Form::radio('sineor_citizan_friendly', true, null),'&nbsp', 'Yes' !!}
    {!! Form::radio('sineor_citizan_friendly', false, null),'&nbsp','No' !!}
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

The `name` should be same with different `value`s. Try with -

```
{!! Form::label('is_kids_friendly','Kids Friendly:') !!}
{!! Form::radio('is_kids_friendly', 'yes', true),'&nbsp', 'Yes' !!}
{!! Form::radio('is_kids_friendly', 'no'),'&nbsp','No' !!}
```

The arguments are - `radio('name of field', 'value', 'checked or not')`

Comment: But i didn't get value yes in my database using above

Answer (score 1):

```
{!! Form::label('is_kids_friendly','Kids Friendly:') !!}
{!! Form::radio('value', 'yes', null),'&nbsp', 'Yes' !!}
{!! Form::radio('value', 'no', null),'&nbsp','No' !!}
```

Try this:
first parameter is name of radio button , second parameter is value, third  is default checked

Comment: But i didn't get value yes in my database using above

Answer (score 0):

You are passing $request->all() directly to the create method, in which case your HTML field's name should be same as the column names in your DB

```
<div class="form-group">
 {!! Form::label('is_kids_friendly','Kids Friendly:') !!}
 {!! Form::radio('is_kids_friendly', 'true', null),'&nbsp', 'Yes' !!}
 {!! Form::radio('is_kids_friendly', 'false', null),'&nbsp','No' !!}
</div>

<div class="form-group">
 {!! Form::label('is_kids_only','Kids Only:') !!}
 {!! Form::radio('is_kids_only', 'true', null),'&nbsp', 'Yes' !!}
 {!! Form::radio('is_kids_only', 'false', null),'&nbsp','No' !!}
</div>

<div class="form-group">
 {!! Form::label('senior_citizen_friendly','Sineor Citizan Friendly:') !!}
 {!! Form::radio('senior_citizen_friendly', 'true', null),'&nbsp', 'Yes' !!}
 {!! Form::radio('senior_citizen_friendly', 'false', null),'&nbsp','No' !!}
</div>
```

Comment: I did changes you suggested, still same problem.

Comment: Update your function to log the query & show the result:
public function store(EventRequest $request) {
  var_dump( $request->all() );
  \DB::connection()->enableQueryLog();
  Event::create($request->all()); 
  echo "<pre>".print_r( \DB::getQueryLog(), true); exit;
}