# How to store radio button value in database using laravel

Tags: php, html, laravel-5, radio-button

I am creating a form, in which I have used radio buttons. For storing radio button's value in database I am using boolean as a datatype, but after submitting form value stored in database is always 0.

here is my code:

**blade:**

```
<div class="form-group">
    {!! Form::label('is_kids_only','Kids Only:') !!}
    {!! Form::radio('kidsonly', 'true', null),'&nbsp', 'Yes' !!}
    {!! Form::radio('kidsonly', 'false', null),'&nbsp','No' !!}
</div>
```

**Controller:**

```
public function store(EventRequest $request) {
     Event::create($request->all());
     return redirect('event'); 
}
```

What can I do, to store the value in database, and when I edit that form, it  should auto select radio button according to database value.

Comment: which database are you using?

Comment: Did you allow kidsonly in mass assignment? You need to add this in your model, like this: `protected $fillable = ['kidsonly'];` http://laravel.com/docs/master/eloquent#inserting-and-updating-models

Comment: Same question, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34289628/radio-button-always-take-boolean-0-in-laravel/

Comment: @Vikas thanks I got answer